# Vertical Space between img

Tags: html, css

I want to create a list with pictures with no spaces between the pictures.
If a picture is bigger than the others, the next picture should fill in the free space. I tried many display styles but I couldn´t find a solution to do that.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXtIO.png

```
<div class="picturelist">
    <div class="pic"><img src="https://localhost/website/includes/img/portrait/pic/1-thumb.jpg" alt="pic"></div>
    <div class="pic"><img src="https://localhost/website/includes/img/portrait/pic/10-thumb.jpg" alt="pic"></div>
    <div class="pic"><img src="https://localhost/website/includes/img/portrait/pic/11-thumb.jpg" alt="pic"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.picturelist
{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    div.pic{
        width: 33%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try flexbox? Guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ attributes are here :  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out Masonry. That is what you want:

https://masonry.desandro.com/

You can also use a CSS trick (columns) to get this to work, like this:

```
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
column-count: 3;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvNJRz

Answer (score 0):

Use display: flex

```
div.picturelist {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: And it is not supporter in IE9.